# Moving Camera in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on rendering a terrain in OpenGL.
My code is the following:

```
void Render_Terrain(int k)
{
    GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (k/40 % 360);

    //PROJECTION
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    //VIEW
    glm::mat4 View = glm::mat4(1.);

    //ROTATION
    //View = glm::rotate(View, angle * -0.1f, glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    //View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.2f, glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
    //View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.9f, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f));

    View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(0.f,0.f, -4.0f)); // x, y, z position ? 

    //MODEL
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0);

    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "MVP_matrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));

    //Transfer additional information to the vertex shader 
    glm::mat4 MV = Model * View;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "MV_matrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MV));

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, terrain_start, terrain_end );

}
```

I can do a rotation around the X,Y,Z axis, scale my terrain but I can't find a way to move the camera. I am using OpenGL 3+ and I am kinda new to graphics.

Comment: Try asking this question at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead, you may have better luck there.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to move the camera would be through the use of gluLookAt(), it simulates camera movement since the camera cannot be moved whatsoever. The function takes 9 parameters. The first 3 are the XYZ coordinates of the eye which is where the camera is exactly located. The second 3 parameters are the XYZ coordinates of the center which is the point the camera is looking at from the eye. It is always going to be the center of the screen. The third 3 parameters are the XYZ coordinates of the UP vector which points vertically upwards from the eye. Through manipulating those 3 XYZ coordinates you can simulate any camera movement you want.

Check out this [link](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm).

Further details:

-If you want for example to rotate around an object you rotate your eye around the up vector.
-If you want to move forward or backwards you add or subtract to the eye as well as the center points.
-If you want to tilt the camera left or right you rotate your up vector around your look vector where your look vector is center - eye.

gluLookAt operates on the deprecated fixed function pipeline, so you should use glm::lookAt instead.

Comment: "literally and not moving the world to simulate camera movement" That **is** moving the world to simulate camera movement. The two concepts are one and the same.

Comment: @NicolBolas Haha, sort of true. The camera cannot be moved whatsoever. They're both the same.

Comment: `gluLookAt` operates on the deprecated fixed function pipeline, so you should recommend `glm::lookAt` instead.

Comment: @TestTest if you have any further inquiries let me know. I've done a lot of camera transformations so if you have a few in mind I could help you with those, tell you how to do them and the math involved and such.

Comment: the link is no longer valid please update your answer

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using a constant vector for translation. In the commented out code (which I assume you were using to test rotation), you use `angle` to adjust the rotation. You should have a similar variable for translation. Then, you can change the `glm::translate` call to:

```
View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(x_transform, y_transform, z_transform)); // x, y, z position ?
```

and get translation.

You should probably pass in more than one parameter into `Render_Terrain`, as translation and rotation need at least six parameters.

Comment: u mean I should change the x y and z, by multiplying them by a sin or cos function and then calling the above ?

Comment: @TestTest, no. Let's back up a bit. What is `k` that you pass to `Render_Terrain`?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL the camera is always at (0, 0, 0). You need to set the matrix mode to GL_MODELVIEW, and then modify or set the model/view matrix using things like glTranslate, glRotate, glLoadMatrix, etc. in order to make it appear that the camera has moved. If you're using GLU, you can use [gluLookAt](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluLookAt_code) to point the camera in a particular direction.

Comment: Well, it seems like he's using GL3 core without any deprecated matrix stuff (or at least without the builtin matrices).